# Does assembler code generated by gcc always use stack frames?

Tags: c, operating-system

same as the title, Does assembler code generated by gcc always use stack frames?

Comment: No, not always. If the function gets optimized, it may use registers for storage and not need a stack frame.

Comment: [No](https://godbolt.org/z/nW5s5PeT8)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.